# Create excel file with two sheets in the same book - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, model-view-controller

In my application, I have a method that return a excel file with one sheet. It works fine, but now I need to create another sheet and add it, and I dont figure out how. Here's my code:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string sFileName = "lottery" + Sorteio.Data.Date.ToShortDateString() + ".xls";

    sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorkBook>");
    sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorkSheet>");
    sb.Append("<table style='1px solid black; font-size:12px;'>");

    //many sb.Append(...) with data

    sb.Append("</table>");
    sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorkSheet>");
    sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorkSheet>");
    sb.Append("<table style='1px solid black; font-size:12px;'>");

    //many sb.Append(...) with data

    sb.Append("</table>");
    sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorkSheet>");
    sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorkBook>");

    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileName);
    this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    this.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
    return File(buffer, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

In the code above, I'm creating the workbook with two worksheets, every one with it's own table, but it only creates me one sheet. Can't figure why it don't work.

Comment: Is there a reason why your doing it this way and not using a library like OpenXML?

Comment: a. Excel file its not a xml. but the new Excell file (from 2007), its a zip pack, include some xml's.
b. the extension its xslx, bot xls.

Comment: Please read the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx OpenXML All office documents back ends are XML based.  You can zip the document after and/or change the document name perhaps from xslx to xls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @xxmrlnxx answer, but adapted to question - proccess the "file" in memory:

```
byte[] ExcellInMemory()
{
    using (var m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        SpreadsheetDocument sDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(m, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

        WorkbookPart workbookP = sDoc.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookP.Workbook = new Workbook();

        WorksheetPart workSheetP = workbookP.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        workSheetP.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        Sheets sheets = sDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        for (UInt32 i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var sheet = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = sDoc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(workSheetP),
                SheetId = i,
                Name = "shhet " + i
            };
            sheets.Append(sheet);
        }

        workbookP.Workbook.Save();
        sDoc.Close();

        return m.GetBuffer();
    }

}
```

use this function like this:

```
string sFileName = "lottery" + Sorteio.Data.Date.ToShortDateString() + ".xlsx";
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFileName);
this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

byte[] buffer = ExcellInMemory();
return File(buffer, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

You might want to implement your own ActionResult, something like this: [Using ASP.NET MVC and the OpenXML API to Stream Excel Files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42628/Using-ASP-NET-MVC-and-the-OpenXML-API-to-Stream-Ex)

Comment: And where I put the excel data? Just like I have it?

Comment: Had modified my answer with base on yours. Its working now. Thanks and thanks also to @xxmrlnxx!

Answer (score 1):

I would use [OpenXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) and the code would be something like.....

```
// Given a document name, inserts a new worksheet.
public static void InsertWorksheet(string docName)
{
    // Open the document for editing.
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, true))
    {
        // Add a blank WorksheetPart.
        WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
        Sheets sheets = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
        string relationshipId = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart);

        // Get a unique ID for the new worksheet.
        uint sheetId = 1;
        if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
        {
            sheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
        }

        // Give the new worksheet a name.
        string sheetName = "Sheet" + sheetId;

        // Append the new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = sheetName };
        sheets.Append(sheet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the SheetData object.